# Active class from LocalStorage with Javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two divs one of them has `is-active` class, what I am trying to achieve is when users click on div it gives them that active class is saved value in localstorage so when the user reloads the page it needs to have that active class on the div on which he is clicked. This is my code

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  if (localStorage.getItem('user') == 'aaa') {
    $(".form-wrapper").addClass("is-active");
  }

  $('.student').click(function() {
    localStorage.setItem('user', 'student');
   ;
    $('.form-wrapper').removeClass('is-active');
    $(this).addClass('is-active');
  });

  $(".teacher").click(function() {
    localStorage.setItem('user', 'teacher');
   
    $('.form-wrapper').removeClass('is-active');
    $(this).addClass('is-active');
  });
});
```

```css
.is-active {
  background-color:red;
  width:40px;
  height:40px
}

.teacher {
    background-color:gray;
  width:40px;
  height:40px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-wrapper student is-active">
</div>

<div class="form-wrapper teacher">
</div>
```

This code works well except one thing, when I click on teacher div, it passes `is-active` class and I can see value in localStorage but when I refresh the page active class is gone but the value is in loaclStorage.

Can anybody try to help me with this?

Comment: Well according to your logic the class should be added onload only if `localStorage.user` is "aaa", and nothing in your code ever sets it to that value - only "student" or "teacher". You also have a typo = `= "aaa"` should be `== "aaa"`.

Comment: @Utkanos even if I removed that part, still code is not working properly

Comment: I ran your code snippet and it says, `"Script error."`.

Comment: @programmerRaj this is my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pz14hkxg/3/

Comment: There is nothing in your Fiddle attempting to reinstate (add) the class onload - it features only code that is executed in event handlers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made some changes to the codes

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ahmetarpaci/gL5x69ab/1/)

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {


    if (localStorage.getItem('user') == 'student') {
        $(".form-wrapper div").removeClass("is-active");           
        $(".form-wrapper .student").addClass("is-active");
    }
    if (localStorage.getItem('user') == 'teacher') {
        $(".form-wrapper div").removeClass("is-active");                   
       $(".form-wrapper .teacher").addClass("is-active");
   }

    $('.student').click(function() {
        localStorage.setItem('user', 'student');
        $('.form-wrapper div').removeClass('is-active');
        $(this).addClass('is-active');
    });

    $(".teacher").click(function() {
        localStorage.setItem('user', 'teacher');
        $(".form-wrapper div").removeClass("is-active");           
        $(this).addClass('is-active');
    });
});
```

```css
    .is-active {
  background-color:red !important;
  width:40px;
  height:40px
}

.teacher, .student {
    background-color:gray;
    width:40px;
    height:40px
}
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-wrapper ">
    <div class="student is-active"></div>
    <div class="teacher"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery you could do something like this:

HTML markup:

```
<div class="text-center">
  <h2>Who are you?</h2>
  <div class="form-wrapper" data-user="student">
    Student
  </div>
  <div class="form-wrapper" data-user="teacher">
    teacher
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS styles:

```
body {
  font: normal 15px/1.5 sans-serif;
  color: #555;
}

.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}

.form-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.form-wrapper:hover, .form-wrapper.is-active {
  border-color: red;
}
```

JS:

```
$('.form-wrapper').click(function(){

    let dataUser = $(this).data('user');

  $('.form-wrapper.is-active').removeClass('is-active');

  $('.form-wrapper[data-user='+dataUser+']').addClass('is-active');

  localStorage.setItem('user',dataUser);

});

if(localStorage.getItem('user') !== null){
  $('.form-wrapper[data-user='+localStorage.getItem('user')+']').addClass('is-active');

}
```

I don't know if you need to have by default an active class set?

jQuery [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s24to6fy/)

Without jQuery the following should work:

```
let formWrappers = document.getElementsByClassName('form-wrapper');
console.log(formWrappers)

for(let i = 0; i < formWrappers.length; i++){

    formWrappers[i].addEventListener('click', function() {

      let dataUser = this.dataset.user;
      localStorage.setItem('user',dataUser);

        if(document.querySelector('.is-active')){
        document.querySelector('.is-active').classList.remove('is-active');
        this.classList.add('is-active');
      }else {
         this.classList.add('is-active');
      }

  });

}

if(localStorage.getItem('user') !== null){
    document.querySelector('[data-user='+localStorage.getItem('user')+']').classList.add('is-active')
}
```

Vanilla [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t9Lg7jbp/)